# Convert uint64_t to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code below:

```
- (id)initWithMediaCollection:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaCollection collectionCategory:(NSString *)collectionCategory
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _mediaCollection = mediaCollection;
        uint64_t persistentID = mediaCollection.persistentID;
        _collectionID = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:persistentID];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I debug and then set a breakpoint. The first time this init method gets run, it works fine:

> persistentID  uint64_t    6071794744315787357
>
> _collectionID __NSCFNumber *  (long)6071794744315787357

The second time, I get these values:

> persistentID   uint64_t   14938043870126423662
>
> _collectionID __NSCFNumber *  (long)-3508700203583127954

Why aren't the values the same the second time around? Why is it negative when I explicitly declared it as unsigned?

Comment: It looks to me like you're logging the ADDRESS of the number, not the value. Post the code that logs the value that's returned.

Comment: That is the value. I deleted the address out of the output before I posted here.

Comment: The debugger is simply showing the NSNumber as a long. The code and the value is fine. It's the debugger being misleading.

Comment: BTW - use `_collectionID = @(persistentID);`. Then your code works no matter what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

numberWithUnsignedLongLong works just fine. Much depends on how exactly you are printing it. Which you conveniently left out.

Comment: I'm not printing it. I'm giving you the direct debugger variable watch output. And I'm using the collectionID variable to query via MPMediaPropertyPredicate. The first example (where the two values match) returns a successful query. The second example (values don't match) returns an unsuccessful query. So the issue is more than just with printing.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `NSInteger` is a "signed" value whereas `uint64_t` is not. Between the two values above, the binary representation are both:

1100111101001110100101111100000100110110000101100011111001101110
1100111101001110100101111100000100110110000101100011111001101110

according to these two sites:

- http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.htm (for the large positive integer <- doesn't deal well with the negative value)
- http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter (for the large negative integer <- doesn't handle the positive value above).

Here's a link to how numbers are represented in binary bits:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations